# How do I load hpvsa.ko (RAID controller B120i) module in Centos 7.1

Tags: centos, raid

When RHEL 7.0 and Centos 7.0 was first released I was able to install OS on B120i raid controller by following official RHEL 7.0 and HP docs:

- Download the B120i controller driver from HP. Files you may need:

  `hpvsa-1.2.12-110.rhel7u0.x86_64.dd` or
  `hpvsa-1.2.10-120.rhel7u0.x86_64.dd.gz` (or latest versions).
- Create USB drive disk (this will be loaded later during OS install). This can be created with the `dd` command. If possible name the flash drive as "OEMDRV". Sample `dd` commmand below.

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=4K
  dd if=hpvsa-1.2.12-110.rhel7u0.x86_64.dd of=/dev/sdc bs=4K && sync
  ```
- During first boot, press "Tab" and pass extra following parameters:

  ```
  modprobe.blacklist=ahci inst.dd
  ```

**Since 7.1 release this no longer works**

I even tried disable signature checking of modules but no luck.

Any ideas?

`lsmod` doesn't show this module to be loaded, but `modinfo` provides info as per usual.

`/var/log/dmesq` shows multiple lines about unable to verify hpvsa and etc.

I tried to force load manually and it seems it loaded, but I couldn't see my logical drives.

Comment: Was googling previously and found following article - seems to be related to my question, but no answer: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=51892

Comment: It's probably just not supported yet. Why would you expect 7.1 compatibility to be ready now?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it was needed to use the proper driver version, so no mpdprobe is required during install. I used **hpvsa-1.2.14-100.rhel7u1.x86_64.dd.gz**
with Centos 7.0 1503-01.

I Googled **hpvsa-1.2.14-100.rhel7u1.x86_64.dd.gz** and downloaded from

- http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_9200a10168684afbbb4efce88a.

I created the disk image with the drivers on a mac using:

```
sudo dd if=hpvsa-1.2.14-100.rhel7u1.x86_64.dd of=/dev/disk2
```

or whatever device is used by the usb stick. Be sure is unmounted.

With this configuration, I managed to install the b120i raid 1 driver and booted as normal.

Do the following during installation:

- Press tab during the initial screen
- Append the following boot commands:

  `modprobe.blacklist=ahci inst.dd`

The first one avoids loading any sata drivers and the second one asks for additional drivers so no duplicated had disks.

I didn't remove the usb stick because it was hard to extract the memory stick without generating problems.

Anyway, it worked.
Cheers.

Comment: Worked great for me on MicroServer Gen8 except the installer found no drivers on the second USB. I ended up copying the .dd to a fat32 USB and renaming it to .iso, as suggested here: https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Installing-Centos-7-on-ML310e-Gen8-v2-drivers-for-RAID-1-B120i/td-p/6718353

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple - answering to my own question :)
During boot - do ctrl+alt+f2, in command line: modprobe -f hpvsa, go back to gui installer, re-scan disks - you should see your logical volumes now.
Problem that hpvsa drivers from HP incorrectly compiled. modprobe -f command forces to load without checking versions.